# Value of LEGO bulk

Tags: shopping

I am interested in purchasing some LEGO from someone who is selling a bulk of 50, 000 bricks weighing about 90lbs. This includes about 150 mini figs, the manuals ( about 100 or so) and some baseplate.  The seller is asking for $850 and I am wondering if this sounds like a good price to pay.

Answer (score 3):

Bulk unsorted LEGO shouldn't cost more than $5-$6 a pound. (Please note that this is for the US.) This DOES NOT include instructions. If the seller wants more, they will have to sort and categorize the elements and minifigs themselves, so buyers can evaluate them better. NEVER allow a seller to include the instructions in the total weight of bulk lots. They are very heavy, worth practically nothing (except for a few expensive sets) and can make you offer more for the lot than it's actually worth.

Comment: Just wanted to amplify the point about instructions: Except for very specific instruction sets they should absolutely NEVER be considered as part of a bulk purchase.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Unless they are very valuable parts. I would not pay more than 600. However, it's important to research what figures and sets/parts are in the bins. It may actually be worth that much, but I would definitely research it first. I once bought just under 80 lb of lego for $230 USD. It took many hours to go through, but once all was said and done, I had pulled out almost $400 worth of Harry Potter figures, 100$ of valuable pieces, and still had about 40 lb left over. This is why it's very important to know what you're buying. It could be worth a lot, or it could be someone trying to rip you off.

Comment: What are some examples of mini figs that have a high value?

Comment: Star Wars, Harry Potter, most figures from movie franchises. Essentially most figures from themes that are licensed products tend to me most valuable. Check out BrickLink to research exact value of certain figures.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably too much, but the value of used LEGO also depends on some things we don't know, like:

- What is the condition of the pieces (many/few scratches)?
- Is (any of) the previous owner(s) smokers?
- What's in the lot? If 80 lbs of it is red 2x4 bricks I wouldn't pay a cent.

(And note that I live in Denmark, not the US, so amounts in $ don't have a precise enough meaning to me, I had to calculate what $850 was before I could say if that was high/low/appropriate).